# TestNg DataBinding : unable to pass parameters to test using databinding

Tags: java, data-binding, testng

My Requirement is to run the test for data given in input file. To achieve, I am using

```
@DataBinding [net.sf.testng.databinding.DataBinding]
```

but i am seeing issue while running

### Error:

> SKIPPED: databindingTest
>       org.testng.TestNGException: 
>       Method databindingTest requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the 
>       @Test annotation.     at 
>       org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:191)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:376)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:451)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1276)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:992)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1082)
>     atorg.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:773)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:623)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1018)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

### Below is the property file which is created :

```
databindingTest.dataSource=json
databindingTest.url=/data/test/availabilityCheck.json
```

Below is the Json file created at location

```
/data/test/availabilityCheck.json in Resource folder 

[{"testInput":
{ "Id": "92901225" }
}]


Test Class :

package com.temp.databinding;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import net.sf.testng.databinding.DataBinding;
import net.sf.testng.databinding.TestInput;

public class validateDataBinding {

@DataBinding
@Test
public void databindingTest(@TestInput(name = "Id") String skuId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("@TestInput(name = \"skuId\") String skuId :: "+skuId );
    }

}
```

Please help in identifying what wrong am doing.

Comment: What alternatives have you tried? What have you learned by researching the problem on the internet? What potential solutions from the internet have you tried, and what were the results?

Comment: I have tried with @DataProvider , which is giving me the expected results.. but  thing here is i have to write  additional code to  read data and passing into test.                                                              
     @DataProvider(name = "getinputdata")

Answer (score 0):

thanks for using TestNG DataBinding. I‘m the author of that library. Unfortunately there is currently no json data source available. You can either use any of the existing data sources (csv, properties, text and xml) or implement the json data source plugin yourself and provide it to the community as a maven artifact. Let me know, if you decide to do so.

Best regards,
Matt